# Running .bat and .cmd files in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, batch-file

When I click on a .cmd or .bat file it opens the cmd application but doesn't make the file run. I went to "Control Panel\Programs\Default Programs\Set Associations" and the current default is set to Windows Command Processor (C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe). When I checked in a computer which runs the .bat and .cmd correctly the current default is Unknown application.
Can anybody help here?

Comment: This is a question for http://superuser.com/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the default values for these reg keys, if they aren't, set them to this:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\open\command - "%1" %*
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\cmdfile\shell\open\command - "%1" %*
```

Hope this helps!